# Perl Regex for Strings with special characters and double quotes

Tags: regex, perl

I have been trying for a regex for a text inside available a config file which has the below content

```
Employee Name="John" 
Address="Sector-15"
```

I am reading the whole config data as a string inside a variable $employeeData

How do I write a regex condition such that the text **Address="Section-15"** if found inside the value $employeeData, I will increment a counter.

I know to write simple regex for strings with characters and numbers but I am struggling with writing a regex for strings to consider double quotes and the '-' character as with Address="Sector-15"

I am trying in this way

```
if($employeeData =~ {regex}) #regex for Address="Sector-15"
{
    increment a variable.
}
```

Any link provided which gives some understanding about these conditions or an answer will be appreciated!

Comment: I think It is not clear what you are trying to match. Are you tryint to match any "Address" line? Or just the ones that have "Section + dash + number" inside the quotes? Must the number be 15 or can it be any other number?... Please, provide several examples of what you want to find and what you don't want to find

Answer (score 2):

A regex to match `Address="Section-15"` might be:

- `/.*/` (Matches anything, so should match this string, too)
- `/^Address="Section-15"\z/` (Matches just the string)
- `/.*=".*"/` (Matches anything followed by a `=` followed by something in double quotes)

The syntax for a regex doesn't contain `{}`:

```
if ($employee_data =~ /Address=".*"/) {
    ++$counter;
}
```

If you want to store the regex in a variable, use `qr//`:

```
my $regex = qr/Address="(.*)"/;
while (my $employee_data = <$config>) {
    ++$counter if $employee_data =~ /$regex/;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried the option /Address=".*"/ . It does nt work

Comment: Note that a perl regex *may* use `{}` (and even other characters) instead of `//`. In fact, the `m{regex}` form is recommended when using multiple-lines regexes

Comment: @Julio: `m{}` or `qr{}` are possible, bare `{}` are not.

Comment: @Sawyer: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? `say 'Address="Sector-15"' =~ /Address=".*"/` prints 1 for me.

Comment: @choroba: I ran the regex with my code but it still does not validate with the given value inside $employeeData.

Comment: @Sawyer: What value is that?

Comment: $employeeData has the above config value (Emp Name and Address) stored inside it. I need to match the regex such that an occurance of such kind is available in the config file. There are other config files as such

Comment: I'm getting 1 even from `perl -wE 'say qq(Employee Name="John"\nAddress="Sector-15"\n) =~ /Address=".*"/'`.

Comment: That is fine, can you try to run with a simple code snippet with if condition and see if the condition return true.

Comment: Show the exact code you use. The code I write works as expected.